# Solr on Tomcat not able to post xml files without error field unknown

Tags: xml, tomcat, ubuntu, curl, solr

I just installed Solr on Ubuntu with the following tutorial:

http://feinan.com/2012/05/19/how-to-install-solr-3-6-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

which got me up and running fine.

But when I want to post a new XML file (like the ones in example/exampledocs), I use the following curl command:

`curl http://localhsot:8080/solr/core0/update -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary @vidcard.xml`

but I continue to get the error:

`ERROR: unknown field 'manu'`

From other QA I understand that this might be something wrong with my schema.xml file. But with a fresh install, I am confused why I would have to pre add each field for all the XML i am about to upload (there is a ton of it and it's not all the same schema so I wonder if I really have to hand map it in schema.xml before doing so).

In addition, I had previously followed the [official tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_2/doc-files/tutorial.html), and using the `java -jar post.jar solr.xml monitor.xml` command to index new xml and that was fine.

But I am interested in being able to update from HTTP as this is how it will integrate with our system.

Full disclosure: I am new to solr (perhaps this is obvious).

**Update** Thanks to @Alexandre Rafalovitch below, I understand a little more about Solr. But the problem remains. For instance I am using the vidcard.xml file from the default Solr install example/exampledocs directory and went in and added the dynamic field endings to all the fields, but I am still getting the error:  `ERROR: unknown field 'manu_s'`

At this, I am trying to figure out what typical newbie pitfall I keep falling into (i.e. getting stuck on some common stuff just after installing, not trying yet to do anything too far out of left field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr needs to know what types the fields are, so it knows how to parse/tokenize them. If you want to tokenize them all the same way, you can use [dynamicField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields) functionality to match multiple names.

Please also note, that the update does not allow you to just send a random XML. It expects specific Solr [Update XML](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages) format.

Comment: thanks, i can see how that might help, though I am still having the same issue after taking the above into consideration. I've updated the original post.

Comment: What is your schema definition that you think should match? You should have either 
><dynamicField name='*s'  
>or <dynamicField name='manu*' or  
><dynamicField name='*' or some such.  
Try going through the Solr tutorial and modifying it step by step until you figure it out. One of the frequent beginner's mistakes is to forget renaming <field> to <dynamicField> when adding the wildcard.